# My UITableView quit showing its delete button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that came with the masterViewController in an Xcode split view template.

When I started working with it, it came all wired up with an edit button in the top left that showed the typical deletion business--the spinny lock button and the delete button on the all left, and it supported a swipe-to-reveal of a delete button on the right side. That all worked, including my delegate call to handle the underlying data function when a cell was deleted.

Somewhere along the way, that has broken, and now when the edit button is pressed, nothing happens. When I slide the cell to the left, it slides, and it stays where it's supposed to, hitched off to the left, but there's no delete button, and nothing happens when I tapped that area.

I have literally no idea what might have changed to have that quit working. Can anyone guide me to what I should be looking for?

My delegate's "shouldDelete" method always returns `YES`. My commitEdit method never gets called, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Toss in some breakpoints to each of the methods that should be called, and see which one's are called, and which ones are not. Then you'll know how far into the "deleting" progress it gets.

Comment: The deleting process isn't the problem, we're not even getting there. I slide the cell's view, and there's no delete button.